# Plotting a Lognormal Distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a lognormal distribution so I can compare it with a histogram of my sample data using the code below but my plot does not look right. Is there something with my code that I am not doing correctly? 
The C array has a length of 17576

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=np.loadtxt(F)
C=data[:,3]

x = np.ma.log(C)
avg = np.mean(x)
std = np.std(x)
dist=lognorm(std,loc=avg)
plt.plot(C,dist.pdf(C),'r')
plt.show()
```

[image: My Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your x data are not in sorted order. Try this

```
ind = np.argsort(C)
xx = C[ind]
yy = dist.pdf(C)[ind]
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'r')
```

Plot just connects all the (x,y) pairs with straight lines, so you need to make sure you trace your function from left-right (or right-left). Alternatively, you can skip the lines between the plot:

```
plt.plot(C, dist.pdf(C), 'ro')
```

Comment: That did it thanks! Can you explain why the data needed to be sorted?

Comment: The plot function basically loops over the x and y data, and draws lines between 'adjacent' points (where 'adjacent' refers to location in the input arrays, not the xy plane). If the data aren't sorted, you 'connect the dots' in an arbitrary way. Sorting the data, on the other hand, connects the dots from left to right in the graph. That is usually what you want for normal functions

Comment: Ahh I did not know that's how the plot function worked. Thank you for the explanation